# Overwrite contents of a row in a csv file with contents from the row above in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file that contains a timestamp and data for each stamp. It basically looks like this:

```
Timestamp,Column_1,Column_2,Column_3,Column_4,Column_5
2021-04-13 11:03:13+02:00,3,3,3,12,12
2021-04-13 11:03:14+02:00,999,999,999,999,999
2021-04-13 11:03:15+02:00,999,999,999,999,999
2021-04-13 11:03:17+02:00,3,48,3,3,3
2021-04-13 11:03:18+02:00,999,999,999,999,999
```

So now I want to run through the file and check if one of the values is "999" (since that is only a placeholder).
If that is the case, I want the contents of the row above to overwrite the "999"'s.
That should go through until it reaches a row where the contens aren't "999", since in that case it should save those values for the next time it finds a "999" row, to overwrite it with.

I already tried with the standard csv library but I just can't get anything to work.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: How does the output look alike after replace ?

Comment: In the example I have given, it should be like that the 2nd and 3rd row now have the values of the first row instead of "999" (the timestamp should stay) and that the 5th row would have the values of the 4th row. I hope this clears it up a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the file in pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv(<file_name>)
```

Then replace all entries having value as 999 with np.NaN

```
df = df.replace(999, np.NaN)
```

And then do the fillna with 'ffill'

```
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks very promising! However when I run it, it doesn't keep the changes. Why is that?

Comment: assign each time the output df to the original one. I just did that in the updated answer